# How to dynamically run code from an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, import, eval

I want my program to download a javascript file from my server and then run the code contained in that file. The downloading part is fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to run the code from the file.

The most obvious answer I can think of (that doesn't work) to would use import:

```
//download the file and save it in the current directory as codeFile.js
downloadCodeFile();

import codeFile from './codeFile.js;

//call it
codeFile();
```

but web pack doesn't allow dynamic imports, so that doesn't work.

I can read the contents of the file doing this:

```
import fs from 'fs'

downloadCodeFile();
const codeFileContents = fs.readFileSync('./codeFile.js).toString();
```

and then I have a string with all the code in it but I don't know how to get it to actually run from that point.

I think there's a potential solution using eval (although I'm not sure how to implement it), but I've been basically told never to use eval so I'm wondering if there's a better solution that I'm missing.

If eval is an okay solution, how would I make that work? If there's a better way, what would that be?

Answer (score 0):

`Webpack 2` allows you to dynamically import your module. For example, you are able to use the next code:

```
import('path/to/your/module')
  .then(module => /* use your module here */)
```

`import()` returns a promise which resolves with the required module.

Also Webpack supports `require.ensure`.

Comment: When I try to compile my program with that kind of import set up but without the file in the directory yet, I get an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. The program needs to be able to start up without the file so it can download it.